# 403 error with WebLogic on some files, but no errors on other files in the same directory

Tags: weblogic, peoplesoft

I've been having a problem where on a new installation of PeopleSoft, my PIA doesn't doesn't seem to have the same files as an existing installation.  When I access my PeopleSoft site, I'm getting a bunch of Javascript errors about missing functions.  When I look in `<PS_HOME>\webserv\peoplesoft\applications\peoplesoft\PORTAL.war\<SITE_NAME>\cache` on my newly setup environment, the contents of the Javascript files don't match what I have in existing environments.

So I decided to try to copy that `cache` folder from an existing environment to the new environment to try to troubleshoot.  Now the problem is that I'm getting a 403 error with a lot of the .gif files in that directory when a PeopleSoft page loads.  It seems like the site is able to access some of the files from the `cache` folder, but not all of them.

For instance, if I enter `myserver.mydomain.com/cs/myenvironment/cache/PT_NAV_BULLET_1.gif` in the browser's address bar, I get a 403 error.

But if I enter `myserver.mydomain.com/cs/myenvironment/cache/PT_NAV_GO.gif`, I can go to that image without a problem.

What could be causing the differences in access?  How is WebLogic determining what files are able to be accessed by a site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /cs/ path is a Servlet. PeopleSoft moves files into the cache from the database. With a standard install, it is common to purge the contents of the ../cache/ and let the /cs/ servlet restore as needed. You should not populate that directory yourself.

As PeopleSoft builds the HTML for a page, it creates resource names, such as PT_NAV_BULLET_1.gif. The image definition in app designer is PT_NAV_BULLET. The _1 is the cache version.

I've had 403's when requesting files out of the cache directory when I'm not first signed into PeopleSoft. This makes sense because the /cs/ servlet is handling the request, and it doesn't know who you are.

Try clearing the ../cache/ directory, restart the webserver, and log into PeopleSoft. It should all work as expected. AFter a sign in, if you look at the cache directory, you will notice it suddenly has lots of *.css, *.js, *.png files.